# rss viewer webpart is missing in sharepoint 2013 how to activate it

Tags: sharepoint-2013

rss viewer webpart is missing in sharepoint 2013 it is shown in default folder and when adding the rss viewer web part from default folder it shows the error 'An unexpected error occurred processing your request. Check the logs for details and correct the problem.'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question, it is about the configuration of an application. It seems more suited for [sharepoint.se].

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding feature might not be enabled, so you should follow this path:

Under Site Settings, click Modify All Site Settings.
Under Site Collection Administration, click Site Collection Features.
Enable Office SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features.

If the problem is not solved, you can try going to the central administration:

Under Central Administration, click on Operations.
Under Upgrade and Migration, select Enable Features On Existing Sites.
Select the appropriate checkbox, and click OK.